# Resistance across materials

Tags: resistors, antistatic, conductivity

I'm planning to use 2 PCBs to sandwich some conductive foam - to use it as a  force sensing resistor (FSR).

[image: fsr]

In order to tie them together and add them to a metalic suport I'll be using M4 metalic screws. My question is:

**Will multiple metalic screws (they have low rest. values around 3ohms) that conduct across materials affect (much) of the resistive output?**

If so I assume that plastic screws are an alternative.

I avoided using glue since it solidifies and the foam itself is only .5 cm thick.

Comment: that entirely depends on the foam resistivity, but the answer is yes, of course. do the screws touch conductive areas of the pcb? i.e., are they in parallel with the foam equivalent resistor or are you only concerned about the different material inside the foam? the latter effect is way less strong, but again, it depends on the foam resistivity.

Comment: a 16cm^2 piece of foam has 200k r at no load;  The screws won't touch the conductive area of the pcb.

Comment: @Vladimir Cravero Since the screw will act as a resistor in parallel I suppose the resistance will drop dramatically and I won't be able to obtain precise results?!

Comment: Using plastic screws will be better, how much better I can't say. I don't think it's possible to give a quantitative answer without simulation or trying, you should include precise information on the geometry of your apparatus.

Comment: Use plastic clips that act like clothes pegs gripping top and bottom PCB thus holding the thing together.

Comment: Plastic Screws will work super

Comment: If you want to use metal screws, you can easily isolate them completely from the PCB and foam with plastic bushings and/or washers. But if the plastic screws are strong enough, that is probably an easier solution.

Answer (score 1):

Like the comments have said, screws are not really the best thing to hold the sensor together. You could try taping the thing together and it would probably get better results than the screws. You can also buy screws with a special coating that insulates them. (Spray paint works pretty well if you want to do it yourself.)

The screws will have an impact. I would avoid using them because there are so many other ways to solve this problem.

Hope that helps!